# Javascript regex to pick all multi line text between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have to extract all the text from 'Between' and 'And' from the text file

```
Between
Krish.R,
Richard ,
Sam.S.M
And
```

My regex `Between(.*)And` works when its all in single line. How can modify to make it work to extract text across multi line data

Comment: /^Between(.*)And$/

Comment: Replace `.` with `[\s\S]` or `[^]`.

Comment: Try /Between((.|\n)*)And/